# How to observe en-/decrypting of data for a UIProgressView?

Tags: ios, swift

I am en-/and decrypting data (about 15MB-20MB per data) with CryptoSwift (Framework, loaded with Cocoapods).

My question is how can I observe the progress and display it in a progress bar (UIProgressView)?

I don't know how to get (and update) the progress of encrypting/decrypting.

```
func aesEncrypt(withKey key: String, iv: String) throws -> Data {
        let data = self
        let encrypted = try! AES(key: key.bytes, blockMode: .CBC(iv: iv.bytes), padding: .pkcs7).encrypt([UInt8](data))
        let encryptedData: Data = Data(encrypted)
        return encryptedData.base64EncodedData()
    }
```

That's my function on how to encrypt data. (Data extension).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. At least you can't with this API. Try encrypting/decrypting block by block (luckily AES is a block cipher), and update the progress bar for each block.

See "incremental updates" in the CryptoSwift AES documentation to get the idea:

```
do {
    var encryptor = try AES(key: "passwordpassword", iv: "drowssapdrowssap").makeEncryptor()

    var ciphertext = Array<UInt8>()
    // aggregate partial results
    ciphertext += try encryptor.update(withBytes: Array("Nullam quis risus ".utf8))
    ciphertext += try encryptor.update(withBytes: Array("eget urna mollis ".utf8))
    ciphertext += try encryptor.update(withBytes: Array("ornare vel eu leo.".utf8))
    // finish at the end
    ciphertext += try encryptor.finish()

    print(ciphertext.toHexString())
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift#aes

Just use `update(withBytes:)` in a loop (preferably on a background thread/queue) and update the progress bar in each iteration (don't forget to do this on the main thread). The smaller your chunk size, the more gradual your progress updates will be.

Here's how one could enumerate the data chunk by chunk:

```
let data = ... // your data goes here
let chunkSize = 64 * 1024
var chunkStart = 0
while chunkStart < data.length {
    let chunk = data.subdata(in: chunkStart..<min(chunkStart + chunkSize, data.length))
    ciphertext += try encryptor.update(withBytes: chunk.bytes)
    ... // update the progress bar here (don't forget to dispatch it to the main thread)
    chunkStart += chunkSize
}
```

A more sophisticated approach would be to use [InputStream](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/inputstream) and [OutputStream](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/outputstream), in which case you wouldn't need to hold the data in memory while encrypting. I leave exploring this possibility as an exercise for the reader. (As long as you're working with a few tens of megabytes at a time you won't be running out of memory. )

Comment: Thank you very much! Will try this out soon. Btw; the data is an image, not a string. So I will have do divide the image into blocks, how would I do that?

Comment: You're great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just tried this out, and it may be my mistake, but I always get (after some time, probably near the end of encryption) a 0x0 error. Does the data always have to be a multiple of the chunkSize? F.ex., the last "block" or chunk is less than the chunk size, wouldn't that lead to an error?

Comment: Oh, that's what min() is for, right? Just saw it, I did not have it in my code so far. Btw, just to let you know, I think it's data.count, not data.length

Comment: Yes, I realized this oversight a few minutes after you’ve accepted the answer, and updated it with `min`.